# Underbraces with text inside a list

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I am using uderbraces to annotate text. When I want to have an itemized list though, the bits of text involving underbraces are awkwardly indented w/r/t the bullet point. Is there a way to have it be normally aligned (non-indented). Example:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\redub}{}
\def\redub#1{%
 \@ifnextchar_%
  {\@redub{#1}}
  {\@latex@warning{Missing argument for \string\redub}\@redub{#1}_{}}%
}
\def\@redub#1_#2{%
  \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
  \color{red}%
  \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
  \color{currentcolor}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item SAMPLE
  \item 
    \[
      \redub{\text{sample}}_{\mathclap{\text{sample}}}}{\text{sample}}
    \]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So, the text under the first bullet point is not indented with respect to the bullet point. The text under the second bullet point is indented. I'm trying to get them to be aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to *display* the equation, put it in inline math mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{xcolor,mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xcolor,mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\redub}{}
\def\redub#1{%
 \@ifnextchar_%
  {\@redub{#1}}
  {\@latex@warning{Missing argument for \string\redub}\@redub{#1}_{}}%
}
\def\@redub#1_#2{%
  \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
  \color{red}%
  \underbrace{\color{currentcolor}#1}_{\color{red}#2}%
  \color{currentcolor}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item SAMPLE
  \item $\redub{\text{sample}}_{\mathclap{\text{sample}}}{\text{sample}}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) in order to use `\mathclap` - [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) alone is insufficient, but it will be loaded by `mathtools`.